# grid.arrange() output adding blank space and extra plot in R Markdown

Tags: r, grid, r-markdown, markdown, transform

I am struggling to figure out how to plot two `transform()` (dlookr library) plots together nicely in R Markdown. The following code results in the output from the picture included with this post. I want the last plot (2x2) and am wondering why the other two are populating as well. How can I only print the last one in Markdown?

```
# payment transformation
payment_log <- transform(my_data$payment, method = "log")
# income transformation
income_log <- transform(my_data$income, method = "log")

grid.arrange(
  plot(payment_log,typographic=FALSE),  # visual of transformation
  plot(income_log,typographic=FALSE),  # visual of transformation
  ncol=1)
```

[image: output]

Comment: What code produced those graphs?

Comment: @Stacker I used `transform()` to use a log transformation on some data that was skewed. `plot()` against the transformed data produces two histograms, before and after the transformation. All my code that does the transformation and then produces the plots is in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two plots can be avoided by wrapping each plot in a `function` call inside `as.grob`, and then passing these variables to `grid.arrange`.

```
library(dlookr)
library(ggplotify)
my_data=data.frame(payment=c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9),
                   income=c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9))
payment_log=transform(my_data$payment, method="log")
income_log=transform(my_data$income, method="log")

x=as.grob(function() plot(payment_log))
y=as.grob(function() plot(income_log))
grid.arrange(grobs=list(x,y), ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is truly fantastic. Thank you so much! If you don't mind explaining, could yo talk through what we are doing with this code? `x=as.grob(function() plot(payment_log))`

Comment: If you do `?grid.arrange` you will see three commands, two important ones being arrangeGrob and grid.arrange. Grob I presume is some word for plot object. So in the code we make a function that calls plot, so the plot doesn't actually do some weird things if we didn't put it inside a function, and then we wrap it inside as.grob. Then pass these variables to the grobs argument of grid.arrange.